# Use 'declare' only for specific properties of a class

Tags: typescript

Say I've a class `C` with a native method `f`, i.e. a method that isn't implemented at TypeScript side. I can express that as follows:

```
export declare class C {
    f(): void;
}
```

However, that forces me to define everything as native too in `C`'s block. Is there a way to have this:

```
export declare class C {
    f1(): void;

    f2() {
        // implemented in TypeScript side
    }
}
```

The only thing I think of is using a stub `@Native` decorator and process that magically using the TypeScript compiler API.

```
export class C {
    @Native
    f1(): void {
    }

    f2() {
        // implemented in TypeScript side
    }
}
```

Also, my intention is to use the TypeScript compiler API to compile TypeScript to ActionScript bytecode. Yeah, that seems odd, but Adobe AIR is still maintained by a company called Samsung Harman. I'm just having an idea for now, not sure how to use it.

Comment: You can't `declare` just a method (see feature request at [ms/TS#48290](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48290)) but you can declare it as a function-valued property like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPgJqm). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! I'd add `readonly` to that too.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance; might be a few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript 3.7 introduced [using the `declare` modifier on property declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier), primarily as a way to define class fields without having any runtime effects, once JavaScript officially started supporting [class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) natively.

So the "obvious" approach would be to mark just `f1` with `declare`... except that doesn't work.  Methods can't be `declare`d:

```
export class C {
    declare f1(): void; // error!
    //~~~~~ <-- 'declare' modifier cannot appear on class elements of this kind.
    f2() { }
}
```

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#48290](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48290) to allow it, but so far it's not part of the language.

---

One possible workaround is to replace method syntax with function-valued property syntax:

```
export class C {
    declare readonly f1: () => void;
    f2() { }
}
```

This is quite similar, although there are some differences in how the compiler treats it... e.g., when you override a class, the override for a function-valued property cannot be a method:

```
class D extends C {
    f1() { } // error
}
```

but since the property is [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#readonly) it won't let you mess with it:

```
C.prototype.f1 = () => { } // error
```

So it depends on your use cases.

---

Another approach is to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to re-open the interface corresponding to the class instance and [add the method to it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces):

```
export class C {
    f2() { }
}
export interface C {
    f1(): void;
}
```

This will let you override with methods:

```
class D extends C {
    f1() { } // okay
}
```

but it also lets you mess with the implementation, since methods cannot be `readonly` (although there is also a feature request for that at [microsoft/TypeScript#22315](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22315))

```
C.prototype.f1 = () => { } // okay
```

So again, it depends on your use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFFMA8AcHsCcAuACAxgGwIYGdvIELIDeoyZyAJuBpvOMgGYCMAFAJQBcyAbrAJYUA3MgD0I5OHjwEAQlLkxAP2XLkAHgC0G5AHIqNOjuQBbWBT4M+ktJgB2t2CkzRo4Wsli20WXBPThjcFtEPFgGZEQACz48AGs+WwoAOnkyBgAmdmJkAF9QPJAoOCRvHDwAYWJUymosOmQ6TApPdABPRiYuLIBeAD4efiFqjKyiXPzQcqToaURHVtck5mRu5B7+sZzRcUlpeFBQGl8AEQlIRCCKCqqQcg7R3O2JKQQJsEKYBBQjvABRG7uIzY2QKBSKX2QCQu8AYmFQ9H+JFu5GY7C4vAEgjehx8eAAYmcLok-gCUaxgZsnrBYphWtiQL9prN5otlqt1iCqTTWkA)